# Using different drawable folders based on screen sizes?

Tags: android, eclipse, directory, drawable

I want to add tablet graphics but android (I use eclipse) is not looking in the correct drawable folder.  I made new folders (in /res) drawable-large-ldpi (for each density) and drawable-xlarge-ldpi (for each density) but when I run the application on my tablet it is still getting the images out of the medium sized drawables folder (drawable-ldpi).  I thought that adding drawable-large and drawable-xlarge would make android look in the correct folder for the screen size but apperently not.

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to implement something, or declare the new drawable folders somewhere.

Comment: Which tablet are you using?

Answer (score 1):

SimonSays is right. For drawable you don't need to suffix large, xlarge etc. You should suffix the device density only like ldpi, hdpi, xhdpi etc. So remove all the folders with drawable-large-* and drawable-xlarge-* folders and just keep drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi etc for each screen density you are supporting.

Comment: If I do that then the displayed graphics are way to small.  If I scale the graphics then they get very blurry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing size and resolution in the folder name. You should use only one of both, not both (`drawable-large` instead of `drawable-large-hdpi`). Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for the correct folder names.

Comment: I still don't get what I should name my drawable folders.  Can I set which drawable folder the application looks in or am I limited to only those five folders?

Comment: You cannot set which drawable a device will look in. It will automatically look in the most appropriate folder.

Comment: @Java, If you want, you can place all your drawables in just one drawable folder. Android is smart enough to look through all those folders, and if doesn't find an exact match for the density/size it needs, it will recurse to the closest largest highest density match and do the appropriate scaling calculations for you. And no, the system doesn't limit itself to just those five folders. For instance, the system has qualifiers for countries and languages, so if I have a drawable-fr_rUS/ folder then I'm telling the system to pick that folder if the device is set to the US and the French language.

Comment: The beauty of that system is that once I start writing my java code, I don't need to add a conditional for every country or every language (just like I don't need to modify my java code for the particular density or size the device has).  I just refer to my drawable and depending on the device my app is installed on, the drawable will be the right one for the particular device it's on (and if the particular folder needed is empty or non-existent, it will cascade down to the drawable folder that makes the most sense for the device it's on).

Comment: And of course, you could always place your bitmaps into the assets/ folder, and use them from there. If you put bitmaps in the assets/ folder, Android will use them as-is without making any adjustments to them. In other words, those bitmaps won't be considered Drawables anymore, and no compensation will be made for the type of screen they're displayed on (unless you decide yourself to manually code your own wrapper classes for taking into account all those different device variations).

Comment: Android clearly is not smart enough.  If I don't manually scale my bitmaps on tablets then the UI looks crapy because all of the images are tiny.  If I scale it then it also looks crapy because the images are blurry.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've replied to your comment on the other answer thread.

Answer (score 0):

Only [0.1% of android devices](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) have both an `xlarge` and an `ldpi` screen at the same time.

Not only that, but you should only use the size qualifiers on a drawable when the drawable is a bitmap image that takes the entire width or the entire height of the screen (like for instance when you use a bitmap image as a background image for the entire screen).

For most drawables (barring the exception I just mentioned), you should get rid of your size qualifiers, and only keep the density qualifiers.

Comment: But then I end up with images that are either to small or blurry

Comment: The default drawable/ folder without a qualifier is mdpi. Instead, you should create a drawable-xxhdpi/ folder, delete the previous drawable/ folder, and provide an xxhdpi image for it (an xxhdpi image is roughly 3 times the size of an mdpi). And even if your tablet is only xhdpi or hdpi, you should provide the highest resolution xxhdpi bitmap and label it as such, so that the system can downscale it as it needs for its own density. But even that is not perfect, the image won't be blurry anymore, but if there is a line that is only one pixel thick, it could disappear as it gets downscaled.

Comment: So if you want your work to be completely error free, you should still try do the downscaling manually yourself and use those five folders. I was only suggesting you use only one drawable folder with xxhdpi as a shortcut, just in case the result didn't need to be perfect. In any case, here is a cheat sheet I use to help me remember the approximate ratio between different Android densities. http://www.doubleencore.com/2014/01/android-design-cheat-sheet/